# When use java regular-expression pattern.matcher(), source does not match regex.But, my hope result is ,source matches regex

Tags: java, regex, string, match

When use java regular-expression pattern.matcher(), source does not match regex.But, my hope result is ,source matches regex.

- `String source = "ONE.TWO"`
- `String regex = "^ONE\\.TWO\\..*"`

```
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            test();
        }

        public static void test() {
            Test stringDemo = new Test();
            stringDemo.testMatcher();
        }

        public void testMatcher() {
            String source = "ONE.TWO";
            String regex = "^ONE\\.TWo\\..*";
            // The result = false, "not match". But, the hope result is true, "match"
            matcher(source, regex);
        }

        public void matcher(String source, String regex) {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

            boolean match = pattern.matcher(source).matches();
            if (match) {
                System.out.println("match");
            } else {
                System.out.println("not match");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why your hope is "true" ? ^^ because it just can't work for many reason, and the easier one is 'W' does not match 'w'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, your regular expression expects the `o` in `TWO` to be lower case and expects it to be followed by a `.`.

Try:

```
String source = "ONE.TWo.";
```

This will match your regular expression as coded in your question.

The expression `\.` means match a literal dot (rather than any character). When you code this into a Java String, you have to escape the backslash with another backslash, so it becomes `"\\."`.

The `.*` on the end of the expression means "match zero or more of any character (except line-break)".

So this would also match:

```
String source = "ONE.TWo.blah blah";
```

Comment: It works for me.  Thank U.  
I can not modify `String regex = "^ONE\\.TWO\\..*" ` ,Because it is response of one API request.  
But I can modify my use ```source```:  
`boolean match = pattern.matcher(source).matches() || pattern.matcher(source + ".").matches();`

Answer (score 1):

Well it doesn't match for two reasons:

- Your regex `"^ONE\\.TWo\\..*"` isn't case sensitive so how do you expect `TWo` to match `TWO`.
- And your regex expects a `.` character at the end while your string `"ONE.TWO"` doesn't have it.

Use the following **[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/mdQw0x/1)**, to match your source string:

```
String regex = "^ONE\\.TWO\\.*.*";
```

Comment: I can not modify ```String regex = "^ONE\\.TWO\\..*" ```,Because it is response of one API request.  But, Thank U all the same.

Comment: @Vicky So you need to adapt the Regex to match it.

Comment: Yes. regex list is the api response.             this regex list  is useful for most data.        
Only Two regex is not useful.      
I must write extral custom regex for the sepecial case.

Answer (score 0):

Pattern matching is case sensitive by Default. In your case source has a uppercase O and regex a lowercase o.

So you have to add `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` or Change the case of o

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE );
```

or

```
String regex = "^ONE\\.TWO\\..*";
```

Comment: I can not modify ```String regex = "^ONE\\.TWO\\..*" ```,Because it is response of one API request.  But, Thank U all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is a bit incorrect. You have an extra dot here:

`String regex = "^ONE\.TWO\.(extra dot).*"`

Try this one, without dot:

`String regex = "^ONE\.TWO.*"`

Comment: I can not modify ```String regex = "^ONE\\.TWO\\..*" ```,Because it is response of one API request.  But, Thank U all the same.

Answer (score -1):

`String regex = "^ONE\\.TWO\\..*"`

The DOUBLE SLASH `\\` in regex is escape sequence to match a SINGLE SLASH `\` in Source string.

The `.*` at the end matches any character `0 or More times` except line breaks.

To match the regex your source should be like

```
String source = "ONE\.TWO\three blah @#$ etc" OR
String source = "ONE\.TWO\.123@#$ etc"
```

Basically its Any String which starts with **ONE\.TWO\** and without line breaks.

Comment: no. backslash must be escaped once for java, and eventually once for the regexp engine (if you need to match a dot, eg. ``"\\\\."``). ``"\."`` is an invalid Java string. this code doesn't compile.